# How to check if month order is ambiguous when inferring dates with pandas.to_datetime()?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

When using `pandas.to_datetime()` it will seem to prefer parsing string dates with the month first.

It seems it will do this ignoring the locale. It also seems it will ignore the formats of other, non-ambiguous dates.

```
>>> import pandas
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale()
('en_GB', 'UTF-8')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['03-04-2019', '14-04-2019'])
>>> pd.to_datetime(df[0]).dt.month
0    3
1    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Here you can see that the first date is parsed as if the first digits are the month. It will do this even though the locale is en_GB, where day is *never* in the middle, and the other date clearly shows the day is the first two digits.

Is there a way to get pandas to warn if there are ambiguous dates, only if the rest of the dates do not exemplify the correct format? Also, is there a way to get Pandas to use the format when other dates in the series clearly demonstrate what the month/day order should be?

Aside:
This seems pretty dangerous to me. It is unintuitive, and pandas is silent about the obvious potential pitfall.

Comment: You can explicitly specify the format or just pass `dayfirst=True` to pd.to_datetime.

Answer (score -1):

You can choose the format.
When you put the pd.to_datetime, you can set the argument 'format' => `pd.to_datetime(format="%d/%m/%Y")`

regards,

Comment: `pd.to_dataframe()` or `pd.to_date()`?

Comment: Sorry, is `pd.to_datetime`